# Is there a way to loop api calls in R

Tags: r

I need to get some weather data via api in R in the time period of 2007-2023. The limit of observation I can get is 300.000. Due to the large quantity of data, I only get 1-2 months worthy of data.

I have thought of reducing the time period to e.g. 2007-2008 and repeat this process until 2023. This process is only for 1 out of 4-5 variables I need to get, so I would have to do this process a lot and it seems very tedious. I would then in the end need to merge it all in to 1 dataset again.

My question is:
Is it possible to extract the data from e.g. 2007-07-01 12:00 and make it loop somehow, but the next day until it reaches 2023.

The thing is that the weather data is updated every 10 minutes, so there are loads of data just for 1 day and I don't need that. I only need for one specific time on that day, which is why I thought if it was possible to loop.

I am starting to learn R and have zero knowledge with coding, which is why I asked chatGTP for help, but that didn't work out.

Hope anyone can help, thanks in advance.

I asked chatGTP if it was possible to loop. It gave me a code, which I tried but it didn't work.

API documentation:
https://confluence.govcloud.dk/display/FDAPI/Meteorological+Observation+API

My original:

```
base_url <- "https://dmigw.govcloud.dk/v2/"
info_url <- "metObs/collections/observation/items?"
req_url <- "stationId=06060&&datetime=2007-07-01T12:00:00Z/2008-11-01T12:00:00Z&limit=300000&parameterId=temp_dry"
api_key <- "&api-key=34616d8a-08f0-4eec-9887-f3b76c29f773
```

The code chatGTP provided:

```
# Define your start date and end date

start_date <- as.Date("2007-07-01")
end_date <- Sys.Date()  # Today's date

# Base API URL and key

base_url <- "https://dmigw.govcloud.dk/v2/metObs/collections/observation/items?"
api_key <- "&api-key=YOUR_API_KEY"  # Replace with your actual API key

# Loop through each date
while (start_date \<= end_date) {

  # Format the date for the API call
  formatted_date <- format(start_date, "%Y-%m-%dT12:00:00Z")

  # Construct the API call URL
  api_call <- paste0(base_url, "stationId=06060&&datetime=", formatted_date, "&limit=300000&parameterId=temp_dry", api_key)

  # Make the API call (you may need to adjust this based on your specific API)

  response <- httr::GET(api_call)

  # Check if the request was successful (status code 200)

  if (httr::http_status(response)$status_code == 200) {
    # Parse and process the API response as needed
    api_content <- httr::content(response, "text")

    # Add your processing logic here
    
    # Print a message indicating success
    cat("API call for date", formatted_date, "was successful.\n")
  } else {
    # Print an error message if the request was not successful
    cat("API call for date", formatted_date, "failed with status code", httr::http_status(response)$status_code, "\\n")
  }

  # Increment the date for the next iteration
  start_date <- start_date + 1
}
```

Error message:

```
Error in if (httr::http_status(response)$status_code == 200) { :
argument is of length zero
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your full code example, replace

```
httr::http_status(response)$status_code  == 200
```

with

```
httr::status_code(response) == 200
```

The `http_status()` response does not have a `status_code` property.